# How to display a map from MapServer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm working on a project with MapServer and I need to display my generated map in OpenLayers, but I'm not understanding how to do this. I've searched but none of the results helped.

I'm using OpenLayers 4.4

Either OpenLayers documentations helped.

I've tried these two exemples that I found on OpenLayers page but none of them worked.

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/arcgis-image.html?q=mapserver

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/arcgis-tiled.html?q=mapserver

I've changed the url to use my source but didn't work.

Comment: List some of your best hits so far and point out what you did not understand.

Comment: Look for WMS.....

Comment: I read about WMS and tried to follow a local exemple that OpenLayers has installed, but neither the local exemple works.

The image tile exemple I put on my question works on my map, but when I try to put what I need, it does not display and sometimes the entire map disapear.